# How to upload a status with a image using facebook sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I has used this to upload a image with a message:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
    [dic setObject:@"a message" forKey:@"message"];
    [dic setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]) forKey:@"source"];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:dic HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error) {
         NSString *alertText;
         if (error) {
             alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                          error.domain, error.code];
             NSLog(@"%@",error);
         } else {
             alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"Posted action, id: %@",
                          [result objectForKey:@"id"]];
         }
         // Show the result in an alert
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                     message:alertText
                                    delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil]
          show];
     }];
```

It works fine and I can see the image in my album,but I it doesn't show the upload status in my home view.How can I upload a image with a message ,and it can be shown in my home view?

Comment: Fixed it.The code is correct.I can see my status in home view later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is completely fine, i think that the problem is that you have to sort your FB stories to **Most recent** from **Top stories**.

[image]